# Producing even cycles in directed graphs - Alon and Spencer, Exercise 3.4

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, directed-graphs, probabilistic-method

Show that there is a finite $n_0$ such that any directed graph on $n>n_0$ vertices in which each outdegree is at least $\log_2(n)-\frac{1}{10}\log_2\log_2n$ contains an even simple directed cycle.

I'm looking for hints on the above exercise - I have no ideas so far. I'm not sure what kind of trick I could use to force cycles to be even.

Edit: My thoughts on some of the comments.

Put each vertex randomly into one of two sets - A and B, and let S be the bipartite subgraph containing precisely the edges between A and B. We find that the expected number of vertices in S with outdegree 0 is at most $n{\frac{1}{2}}^{\log_2n-\log_2\log_2n} = \log_2n$. This doesn't suffice. I've thought about deleting vertices of outdegree 0, but I haven't been able to make that work.

Comment: If you can find a directed bipartite subgraph with all vertices having outdegree $\geq 1$ then you have an even cycle.

Comment: Adding on, https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~fan/wp/even.pdf may not help in this specific problem, but is a nice theorem to show even cycles for strongly connected directed graphs.

Comment: A general Alon and Spencer hint is to carefully go through the preceding chapter, and think about whether the technique used to solve any example would be helpful for you in this problem. (In this case, because the exercise has a * next to it, this approach still helps, but you will have to think out of the box.)

Comment: If there is a cycle with diagonal, then there is an even cycle. If every cycle has no diagonal then graph is too sparse

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis If I randomly throw each vertex into two sets, A and B, and consider the subgraph with edges only between A and B; then I find that there are less than \log_2(n) vertices with out degree 0. But this isn't enough, so I'm not sure what to do

Comment: @Smylic can you elaborate? I'm not sure how to use your hint

Comment: @ratatouille I'm sorry the first part is not true for directed graphs